# C# List size limit for web service

Tags: c#, list, max

Is there a size limit for Lists when sending it to a web service? I'm currently trying to send a rather large list to my web service, but it gives me a "Not Found" exception. Limiting the list to 5 objects, it works great.

Comment: Please add some code and the configuration for your webservice

Comment: Look at this [search](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=web+services+size+limitations)

Comment: What kind of web service is it (WCF? Web API? ASMX? Other?) and how are you hosting it? Both ASP.NET and IIS have maximum request size limits that are configurable.

Comment: could you please add more info ..